How to send data from Chrome extension's background script to a React app without using query params?
I have some data that I gather on the extensions background script. Then I create a new tab and open my React app hosted locally on localhost:4200 (for now). And I tried sending the data in the URL as a query param. However, the React app throw 431 error.
chrome.tabs.create({ url: `http://localhost:4200?data=${encodeURIComponent(data)}` });

I want to send data from the extension's background script to the newly created tab.

You can use externally_connectable messaging i.e. the app asks for the data and the background script responds.
